# On Join Message That is Only Sent Once Per Join

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm wondering about a potential command block program that will give a player a Unique id that I can use for multiple things. Just I need the command to pick up every single id that has joined that day (All ids reset at midnight) And know when they leave, so they can tag that id with `leave` when they join however it gives them the tag `join`. Once they join and lose the `leave` tag, they are given an actionbar message. If there is a simpler way please tell me!

Note: basically my goal here is to detect when someone leaves, and when they join gives them a message that is once per join. When they rejoin they get the message again, but never get it again per that session on the server.

Edit: So Its Kinda Of A Arena server so when you join I want to to say in the actiobar `&7Welcome, You Are In Arena &C&l1`. And Then Shut Off after about 2 seconds or so. The session is when someone joined until they leave. Not a first time join thing, it is sent every time the player joins.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Not your fault for being Mr. Bad Grammar, but I am struggling to understand, do you want to send an action bar message every time someone joins?

Comment: You mention tags being reset at midnight but then you also refer to a session as a length of time.  Is a session one day?  Is midnight real world time or minecraft time?  Also, the section about join/leave tags and when you do/don't want messages sent is very difficult to understand.  I would suggest editing the question.

Comment: @Frank Yes I Have Tried, When the player leaves the get the tag `join`. If they have the join tag when they rejoin the server they get a message. Then the tag `join` is removed. Im stuck at the part where when they leave they are tagged with `join` in which restarts the cycle. @MBraedly I am glad you tryed to find a duplicate but my problem is I want the message to appear every time they join. @54D Thanks for not making fun of my grammar, and yes I do. @IronAnvil I kinda misused the word session in the question, and theres really no need for it to be there.

Comment: Great! *So show us what you've tried.*  Effort helps us help you.

Comment: I can't really explained what I have tried. But what I can tell you is My main problem is trying to detect when a single person leaves and tagging that single person

Comment: Why not? Showing effort is a core tenet for Arqade; its not necessary, but you'll get a much better response if you do. Just saying you can't isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that uses scoreboard with `stat.leavegame`

First, you have to create an objective.  Type this into chat:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Leave stat.leaveGame
```

Then I used two chains of command blocks:

[image: Blocks]

**Chain 1**

*The first command block* sends the message to any player not tagged with `Sent`.  I used tellraw in this example but this is where you would put your actionbar command.  It is a repeating / unconditional / always active block with command:

```
tellraw @a[tag=!Sent] [{"text":"Welcome! You are in arena ","color":"gray"},{"text":"1","color":"red","bold":true}]
```

*The second command block* tags the untagged player with `Sent`.  It is a chain / conditional / always active block with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!Sent] add Sent
```

**Chain 2**

*The first command block* removes the `Sent` tag from any player with a `Leave` score of 1 or higher.  It is a repeating / unconditional / always active block with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a[score_Leave_min=1] remove Sent
```

*The second command block* resets the `Leave` score of the player with a score of 1 or higher.  It is a chain / conditional / always active block with command:

```
scoreboard players reset @a[score_Leave_min=1] Leave
```

---

On first join, player will be sent message and tagged.  Once they leave, they will have a `Leave` score of one.  When they rejoin, they will be untagged, and the score will reset.  Then the first chain will send the message and tag them again.

In this example, every time I join, I see:
[image: Message]

If you are wondering about the lever in my image, both of the repeating command blocks are set to Needs Redstone so I can turn it off.